# Remote Control WM 6.5 device without being in the same network

Tags: windows-mobile, remote-access

Is there a way to remote access a device running Windows Mobile 6.5 from a desktop?

In my case, the devices could be connected to the internet on two different ways:

- via a hotspot through their mobile
- via a SIM-card

After a quick google search it seems that there are several ways to do this (like `MyMobiler`), but only if the device is connected with USB/ActiveSync or if the device is in the same WiFi-network.

Things I would like to accomplish with remote access:

- Access the device of course, executing software, etc; Like a usual RDP connection
- Copy files from the device on to my desktop (would be the database I'm using with in my application, a SDF-file)
- And also copy files back to the device

Is there a tool/software out there to do this?

Answer (score 0):

MyMobile should be able to be used in any network, but you have to use the IP connection. When used within internet, your firewall settings etc. must be adjusted to allow the MyMobiler TCP/UDP ports for incoming connections. Possibly the connection ports are blocked by some ISP (if used in GSM/CDMA networks).

There are alreday some management solutions that provide remote access to any mobile device with an agent installed: I can list some here (without being a complete list):

- AirWatch
- SOTI Mobile
- Wavelink Avalanche
- (Intermec) SmartSystems

...

Note: Using remote view over GSM may be slow and unreliable.

There are vendor specific MDM and independent MDM solutions.